# What are the groups $D_4$ and $S_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

My professor gave us this question in a practice midterm and showed us how its done but I just want to make sure I have a better understanding of what $D_4$ to $S_2$ means in the example. My understanding is that $D_4$ is a group with elements up to order 4 and $S_2$ is a group with elements up to order 2, is that correct? Do the letters D and S mean something specific or is that to signify they are different from eachother?

"If we label the diagonals in the square by 1 and 2, every isometry of the square would permute them. This gives a homomorphism from $D_4$ to $S_2$. Describe its kernel and image."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D_4$ is the dihedral group of order $8$ (symmetries of the square). $S_2$ is the symmetric group on $2$ elements (group of permutations.)

$S_2$ is basically just the identity element, and the permutation that swaps two elements.

$D_4$ has presentation $\langle r,s: r^4=s^2=e, (rs)^2=e \rangle$,
but basically it just consists of rotations and reflection symmetries on a square.

The point is that $D_4$ can act on the vertices of a square, so we can describe, for exmaple a $90$ degree rotation as $(1,2,3,4) \mapsto (2,3,4,1)$, where $(1,2,3,4)$ is some ordering of the vertices. If we restrict our attention to diagonals of the square, then call the diagonal between $2$ and $4$ diagonal $a$, and the other one diagonal $b$. Then the same $90$ degree rotation, makes the diagonals switch places  (draw a picture), so this corresponds to the permutation $(ab)$ that swaps $a$ and $b$. Rotating again will switch them again, so we get $(ab)(ab)=e$. In particular, I'm saying that $r \mapsto (12)$ and $r^2 \mapsto e$, so the first is in the image, the second in the kernel.

Comment: We have to be careful with dihedral groups because there are different conventions in different sources. Sometimes $D_{2n}$ will be used for the symmetries of a regular n-gon, and sometimes $D_n$ will be used for the same group. The group's order is $2n$.

Comment: I know, but the square is explicitly mentioned by in the OP, which leads me to believe that the teacher is referring to the latter convention.

Comment: Indeed so, but just wanted to alert OP to the issue.